# How to split data with square brackets while declaring parameter in json

Tags: javascript, json

I am passing some data from js file to handler which in turn gets result from SP. I have a parameter like ID = abc[123]. but i have to pass only 123 as value to ID to SP.
This is how im declaring parameter in js

```
var parameters = JSON.stringify({
    "ID": JSON.stringify(EditedID).replace(/]|[[]/g, '')
     });
```

But i am getting error like invalid ID
Kindly help

Comment: What is EditedID here? Can't get ur question clearly!

Comment: Im passing the latest ID which i declared as edited ID

Comment: u want to split ur edited Id or replace [] square brackets? pls give an eg. of edited id and wat u want it to become.

Comment: I also don't understand completely, but if you're trying to turn `'abc[123]'` into `'123'`, then this is one option (logs first string of digits):

`const matches = 'abc[123]'.match(/\d+/); if (matches) console.log(matches[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are replacing the regex with empty space, so it will return the result 'abc123'. What you actually need is getting the string inside the brackets. You can use the below code to do it.

```
var EditedID = "abc[123]"
var regex = /\[([^\[\]]*)\]/
var result = ""
match = JSON.stringify(EditedID).match(regex)
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1]
}
```

"result = match[1]" means that it will assign the value inside the brackets to result. If you want the value with both brackets, use match[0].

I assume that your EditedID is an object and somehow it will need the method "JSON.stringify" to make it become String. If your EditedID is already a String, just replace the match value to make it simpler

```
match = EditedID.match(regex)
```

If there is not match, the code won't run into the if condition so the value of result will just be an empty String.